Sangaku of Yamagata. Six touching circles.
This is the first problem from the Yamagata Yakushido Sangaku. It can be found here (via wasan.jp).

Problem
There is an outer circle with a radius of 9. Draw a horizontal line and construct a larger (red) circle that is tangent to this line and also touches the outer circle. Determine the radius of this larger circle such that:

Two small (green) circles can be drawn that are tangent to the horizontal line, the larger circle, and the outer circle.
Two medium-sized (yellow) circles can be drawn, each tangent to the larger circle, the small circles, the outer circle, and the other medium-sized circle.

The solution given in the Sangaku is that the radius of the larger (red) circle is 5.
I tried to solve this problem using analytic geometry, but the calculations became overwhelmingly complex. I couldn’t find any related reference or solution online, and this problem has been puzzling me. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

This problem can be solved using circle inversion. Try invert everything with respect to any circle centered at contact point of red and outer circles.

To find the radius of the red circle, I will use inversion. Firstly, I label some points as follows:

The outer circle touches the red circle at $O$. $OA$ and $OB$ are the diameters of the red and outer circles, respectively. The center of the outer circle is $C$. $D$ is the midpoint of $AB$. The tangent line $\ell_{A}$ at $A$ of the red circle intersects the outer circle at $M$ and $N$. $\ell_{B}$ is the tangent line at $B$ of the outer circle.


We use the inversion $f$ whose center is $O$ and power is $OA\cdot OB$. An inversion possesses the following properties:

it maps a line containing the inversion center to that line
it maps a circle not containing the inversion center to a circle not containing the inversion center
it maps a circle containing the inversion center to a line not containing the inversion center
it is a conformal map (it preserves angles and tangencies)

$OA\cdot OB = OM^{2} = ON^{2}$. The inversion $f$ maps:

the red circle to $\ell_{B}$ (and vice versa), the outer circle to $\ell_{A}$ (and vice versa),
the green circles to circles that touch $\ell_{A}, \ell_{B}$ and the outer circle,
the yellow circles to circles that touch $\ell_{A}, \ell_{B}$, and $OA$.

Consider a green circle and the yellow circle that touches it. Denote by $\odot(I)$ and $\odot(J)$ the images of these circles under $f$. Because these images are mutually tangent and tangent to parallel lines $\ell_{A}, \ell_{B}$, the radius $x$ of these two circles is $\frac{AB}{2}$ and $ID = 3x$. At this point, one can establish an equation and solve for $x$.
Hint: Express the length of $CI, CD, DI$ in terms of $x$ and apply Pythagoras' theorem to triangle $CDI$ to establish an equation.

You beat me to it with inversion! :-) A nice alternative centre of inversion is the point where the red circles touches one of the yellow circles - this gives you two parallel lines with three circles "sandwiched" between them.

Actually, I’ve never heard of inversion before, but it sounds like an interesting topic that I plan to study in the future. For now, I need help expressing CI in terms of x.

@bowen951209 Because $\odot(I)$ touches the outer circle externally, $CI = x + 9$.

Oops, I missed that.Now I can solve this.

@ChrisLewis I got this idea from the Pappus chain of circles, it is a very nice application of inversion.
